# Application closes when click button

Tags: android

I've made a button that opens a link on the internet and I have a button to swap to another activity, both codes have no bugs in them, but when I run the app and click them the app crashes.

Button to link:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fourth_layout, container, false);
}
public void buttona1(View view){
    Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.nl"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

Button to activity:

```
View myView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fifth_layout, container, false);
    return myView;
}
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent myintent = new Intent(FifthFragment.this.getActivity(), startGamee.class);
    startActivity(myintent);

}
```

This the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.jannes.app, PID: 23465
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method startgame(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button11'
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10814)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 23465 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: The exception message is pretty clear. Apparently you're trying to use a method that the object doesn't have. Have you looked into that?

Comment: The error is self explanatory : `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method startgame(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class `

Comment: Well I'm pretty new to programming. What do you mean?

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Comment: @John Joe yeah thanks works now!!!

Comment: @JannesvandenBogert congratz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure in your `fourth_layout` you have this

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="buttona1" 
    android:id="@+id/button11"/>
```

Refer from [Android unable to find my onClick method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30920327/android-unable-to-find-my-onclick-method)

Or this

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fifth_layout, container, false);
    Button btn1 = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.button11);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               buttona1(); // call buttona1 method
            }
        });
        return myView;
    }
```

Then

```
public void buttona1(){
    Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.nl"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the value you put on your button's attributes
`android:onClick="startGame"`
should be the same as the name of your function called by clicking the button

```
public void startGame(View view){}
```

Comment: Well there 2 different buttons with both different functions.